# .htaccess RewriteCond – adding multiple exceptions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My question is very simple, but I want to get it absolutely right the first try, because I'm working on a live website and bad things could happen if I blew this :)

So, as a part of a RewriteRule that forwards all my regular visitors to /myfolder/, there is an important line preventing the rule from being applied if you're already in that folder:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myfolder/
```

That works fine. What I want is to add my dev folder to that exception, so myself and my clients can access my development projects while all other URI's still get forwarded to /myfolder/

I'm guessing I need to modify the RewriteCond along the lines of:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myfolder/
```

(here I basically need 'OR' in the right syntax) !^/dev/

What's the correct syntax for this?

Comment: In fact, I think I need 'AND' instead: 'If the folder is not /myfolder/ AND the folder is not /dev/ then do this'n'that.'

Comment: `(foob|bar)` is `foo` or `bar` in regular expressions, and to negate that you can place the `!` in front of the whole expression.

Comment: Thanks! To parse that, is the following correct: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/myfolder/|/dev/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(myfolder|dev)/ [NC]
```